# Execute a Go script from Django webapp safely

Tags: python, django, go

How do you launch a Go script in a django app **safely**?

I made a go script which is self contained. I would like to be able to launch a job from a django web app (I use celery to have the job run in the background). What would be the proper/safer way of achieving this? Maybe a way to isolate this process?

I feel that running...

```py
os.system(f"./goscript -o {option1} -b {optiom2}")
```

...is quite unsafe.

as a bonus, I'd like to be able to get the output to see if the script crashes etc... but that is a bonus question.

Comment: It is not unsafe. It is the only way. You write executable programs using go, not scripts.

Comment: yeah, i get that, but wondered if there was a proper way to do it. Even though i sanitise the options, they are from a form and rce looks possible. maybe there could be some sort of container to isolate the execution?

Comment: Does os.system run the program using a shell? Maybe you can find a way to execute the go program without a shell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the people who've answered. I've actually justed remembered that a much better solution would be to use an asynchronous messaging queue library. The one I'm familiar with, and this is very easy to adapt is ZMQ https://zeromq.org/. It's dead easy to do a server/client setup with the Go script listening as a server and the django app requesting as a client for a job.

As a proof of concept, here's a snippet from the documentations of the different libraries.

### Server in GO

- This script is the server, written in Go, I beleive it can be set as a service to run continuously, waiting for django to send a job to do.

```golang
// source: https://github.com/pebbe/zmq4/blob/master/examples/hwserver.go
//
//  Hello World server.
//  Binds REP socket to tcp://*:5555
//  Expects "Hello" from client, replies with "World"
//

package main

import (
    zmq "github.com/pebbe/zmq4"

    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    //  Socket to talk to clients
    responder, _ := zmq.NewSocket(zmq.REP)
    defer responder.Close()
    responder.Bind("tcp://*:5555")

    for {
        //  Wait for next request from client
        msg, _ := responder.Recv(0)
        fmt.Println("Received ", msg)

        //  Do some 'work', can take a whilst
        time.Sleep(time.Second)

        //  Send reply back to client
        reply := "World"
        responder.Send(reply, 0)
        fmt.Println("Sent ", reply)
    }
}
```

### Client in python

- Here is the python app that can be easilly called within any http request. It can create the zmq context and start sending stuff to do to the go server.

```py
#   source: http://zguide.zeromq.org/py:hwclient
#
#   Hello World client in Python
#   Connects REQ socket to tcp://localhost:5555
#   Sends "Hello" to server, expects "World" back
#

import zmq

context = zmq.Context()

#  Socket to talk to server
print("Connecting to hello world server…")
socket = context.socket(zmq.REQ)
socket.connect("tcp://localhost:5555")

#  Do 10 requests, waiting each time for a response
for request in range(10):
    print("Sending request %s …" % request)
    socket.send(b"Hello")

    #  Get the reply.
    message = socket.recv()
    print("Received reply %s [ %s ]" % (request, message))

# Gracefully closing the sockects
socket.close()
context.term()

# Back to normal django stuff
```

What's creat with this approach is that the clieant can dynamically creat and shut down the zmq context. Furthermore, you don't even have to have the go script running on the same server. You could communicate to any IP addresses. Provided you take the care to at least encrypte the packages, o look at the security features ZMQ provides.

--

note: I know I'm answering my own question, but it's like telephoning IT, you need to phone them to solve the problem right when they pick up the phone

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should help IMHO

```py
import shlex
import subprocess

def get_output(command, working_folder=None):
    logging.debug("Executing %s in %s", command, working_folder)

    try:
        output = subprocess.check_output(shlex.split(command), cwd=working_folder)
        return output.decode("utf-8")
    except OSError:
        logging.error("Command being executed: {}".format(command))
        raise
```

Comment: I just wanted to leave a comment here as well. Having a webserver, open to the internet, able to run code in shell, is always a bad idea as it is prone to remote code execution attacks.  [https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/Command_Injection](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/Command_Injection). Thanks for the feedback anyway